# phpMyAdmin import error #1064 "You have an error in you Sql syntax"

Tags: sql, import, phpmyadmin

SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `customatic`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table 'admin'
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  'admin'(
    'id'INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    'Username'VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    'Password'VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    'Firstname'VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
    'Lastname'VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
    'Level'TINYINT( 4 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (  'id' )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =2;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''admin' (
>     'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     'Username' varchar(50) NOT' at line 11

Answer (score 0):

This worked properly without the '' marks

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin(
    id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    Username VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    Password VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    Firstname VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
    Lastname VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
    Level TINYINT( 4 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =2;
```